# Trying to pull out the date from the File Name to turn it in to a metricdate using Regex/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, date, domo

I have a file the name is: security_public_storage_account_performance_10_1_2021_to_10_31_2021.xls
I am trying to use regex to pull out both those dates in the file name. I am using

Start Date: REGEXP_REPLACE(`_FILE_NAME_`, '^.**(\d{1,2})*(\d{1,2})*(\d{4})*to*(\d{1,2})*(\d{1,2})_(\d{4}).*$', '$1/$2/$3')

End Date: REGEXP_REPLACE(`_FILE_NAME_`, '^.**(\d{1,2})*(\d{1,2})*(\d{4})*to*(\d{1,2})*(\d{1,2})_(\d{4}).*$', '$4/$5/$6')

The result for both is reflecting: 10_1_2021_to_10_31_2021.xls

This is SQL. How can I get these dates to be separated to show 2 separate dates instead of just the 2 dates showing as 1?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? date/time and regexp are areas where many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: @jarlh I am just using the ETL in Domo.